# How to work with checkboxes generated from ezMark?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, smarty

I'm using ezMark library in my website alongwith PHP, Smarty, jQuery, etc. Here on one of the webpages I want to disable few checkboxes depending on some condition. After that there is one parent check box, upon selection of which all the checkboxes which are not disabled should get checked and should work vice-versa on deselcting the parent check box. Also after checking the parent checkbox if I uncheck any one of the selected checkboxes(which are not disabled) the parent checkbox should also get unchecked. I tried alot to achieve this by regular code of checking and uncheking the checkboxes `(.attr('checked','checked')` and `.removeAttr('checked');` respectively) but doesn't work in this situation due to ezMark library. Now I'm using following code to check and uncheck the checkboxes as follows:
**Code for parent check box:**

```
<p id="parentCheckbox" class="custom-form"> 
  <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="" id="ckbCheckAll">
  <a class="drop" href="#">more</a> 
</p>
```

**The smarty code for multiple checkboxes creation:**

```
{section name=tests loop=$all_tests}
<p class="custom-form"> 
  <input class="custom-check checkBoxClass" type="checkbox" name="" id="" {if $all_tests[tests].is_test_lock!=1 && $all_tests[tests].test_assign_to_package=='no'} {else} disabled {/if}>
  <label>{$all_tests[tests].test_name}</label>
</p>
{/section}
```

**The jQuery code for selecting and deselectiong the checkboxes upon parent checkbox:**

```
$(document).ready(function()  { 
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () { 
  if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)'))
    $(".ez-checkbox").removeClass("ez-checked");

  if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $(".ez-checkbox").addClass("ez-checked");
  });
});
```

When I look into Firbug Element Inspector I'm getting the different HTML created for the child checkboxes as follows:

```
<p class="custom-form">
<div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked">
<input id="" class="custom-check checkBoxClass ez-hide" type="checkbox" name=""></input></div>
<label>N1P: Gravitation</label>
</p>
```

I'm not getting from where this `<div>` tag is coming. So in order to check and uncheck all the child checkboxes on selection of paren checkbox I'd written above logic. The normal logic is not getting worked due to this `div` tag and ezMark library. With the current code all the child checkboxes are getting selected including the disabled ones upon selecting the parent checkbox and upon unchecking the parent checkbox all the child checkboxes get unselected. Can you help by showing how to achieve the required functionality of selection and deselection of child checkboxes in this scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: inputs are self closing `<input />` - *this is just a note and (probably) has no impact on your issue.*

Comment: ahh, and looking back it looks like FireBug or the pre processor did this. Disregard previous statement.

Comment: @rlemon: For your reference I'm giving you one link as follows:
http://www.itsalif.info/content/demo-ezmark-jquery-plugin/
Go here and see how th <div> tag is getting added in firebug. This is really arising big issues in front of me. Please help me out from this. Thanks for giving your attention.

Comment: yea I didn't answer because the question is not in my realm of expertise, however I did note the input in the rendered output being wrong hence the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery.ezMark](https://github.com/itsalif/ezMark) generated structure is not really a problem to achieve what you want to. I wrote [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BELM/) to show you a way to proceed based on css classes to identify parent (`.l0`) and children (`.l1`).

I manually disabled some checkboxes for sample, but you can use your condition to disabled them.

Hope this can help you ;)

Comment: I am using ezmark checkbox in my webpage, the problem is when i click on a button to add the checked values to a table, it works for once, then it keeps returning nothing. any help plz

Comment: You should open a separate question for this and provide your js and html code